# Plot.ly map not rendering in shiny app

Tags: r, plotly, shiny

I am having trouble getting a shiny app to render a plotly map.

The error message I am getting is: object 'STATE' not found

The plotly portion essentially comes from this tutorial: https://plot.ly/r/shinyapp-map-click/#shiny-app

Not sure if it has to do with my reactive elements or not. The reactive elements worked fine to create a ggplot map. Any help is appreciated.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


state_tot <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bkreis84/Data-604---Model/master/VIS/codeS.csv")


ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("IRS Tax Data 2010 - 2015"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(

        selectInput("var", 
                    label = "Select Variable:",
                    choices = c('Unemployment $ per Return' = 'UNEMP_COMP_PR', 
                                '% of Returns with Business Income' = 'PERC_BUSINESS_RETURN', 
                                '% with Real Estate Deduction' = 'PERC_RE', 
                                'AGI Per Return' = 'AGI_PR'),
                    selected = '% with Business Income'),


        sliderInput("yr",
                     "Select Year:",
                     min = 2010,
                     max = 2015,
                     value = 2015)



      ),


      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        plotlyOutput("plot")



      )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {

  select <- reactive({
    year_sel <- input$yr

  })  

  df <- reactive({
    state_tot %>%
      filter(YEAR == select())
  })

  high <- reactive({ 
    switch(input$var,
           "PERC_BUSINESS_RETURN" = "green",
           "AGI_PR" = "green",
           "PERC_RE" = "green",
           "UNEMP_COMP_PR" = "red")
  })

  low <- reactive({ 
    switch(input$var,
           "PERC_BUSINESS_RETURN" = "red",
           "AGI_PR" = "red",
           "PERC_RE" = "red",
           "UNEMP_COMP_PR" = "green")
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    g <- list(
      scope = 'usa',
      projection = list(type = 'albers usa'),
      lakecolor = toRGB('white')
    )
    plot_ly(z = df()[[input$var]], text = df()[[STATE]], locations = df()[[STATE]],
            type = 'choropleth', locationmode = 'USA-states') %>%
      layout(geo = g)
  })



} 

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in this line:

```
plot_ly(z = df()[[input$var]], text = df()[[STATE]], locations = df()[[STATE]]
```

Since `STATE` is not quoted, you are telling R to look for the column of which the name is stored in the object `STATE`. If you want to fetch the column called "STATE", you should quote the word, so:

```
plot_ly(z = df()[[input$var]], text = df()[["STATE"]], locations = df()[["STATE"]]
```

Or alternatively assign the value "STATE" to the object `STATE` with `STATE <- "STATE"`. It's not a really nice solution but it may help you understand the problem better.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That was it. Thank you!